# Proof of a Landau-inequality

Tags: inequality, computational-complexity

I have to prove or disprove the following:
$$ 2xlog_{10}((x+2)^2) + (x+2)^2log_{10}(\frac x2) \in O(x^2log_{10}(x))$$

My approach (with $log$ is meant $log_{10}$):

$4x log(x+2) + (x+2)^2log(x) - (x+2)^2log(2) \le c x^2 log(x)$

$4xlog(x) + (x+2)^2 log(x) - (x+2)^2 log(x) \le c x^2log(x)$

$4 \le cx$

For example for $c=1$ and $x \ge 4$ the inequality is correct. But if I plot it in WolframAlpha, I can see it is obviously not correct. Where's the mistake?
[WolframAlpha Plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2*log%28x%29+-+%284xlog%28x%2B2%29+%2B+%28x%2B2%29%5E2+*+log%28x%2F2%29%29++from+0%3C%3Dx%3C%3D50&a=*FunClash.log-_*Log10-)

Comment: Not understandable for me. The first formula makes no sense AFAIK. There is $x$ and $x$ and maybe the $\epsilon$ should mean something as "is of order $O$". But why is a function of $x$ of order $O$ of a function of $n$?

Comment: typo, I corrected it ... and yes, the $\epsilon$ means "is of order O" . I'm not a native, what's the english notation?

Comment: The usual notation you can find by googling "landau symbol". One can write $f\ =\ O(g)$ or f\ \in\ O(g)$, but not $f\epsilon g$. Still in the third inequality the term before the inequality sign is wrong and the fourth inequality makes no sense to. Further it seems that you are not sure if you want to show (a) $f(x)=O(g(x))$ or (b) $f(x)-g(x)=O(1)$, since the graph from Wolfram shows the difference. So what are you looking for precisely (a) or (b)?

Comment: The usual notation you can find by googling "landau symbol". One can write $f = O(g)$ or $f\ \in\ O(g)$,butnot $f\epsilon g$.Still in the third inequality the term before the inequality sign is wrong and the fourth inequality makes nosense to me.Further it seems that you are not sure if you want to show(a) $f(x)=O(g(x))$ or$ (b)f(x)-g(x)=O(1)$, since the graph from Wolfram shows the difference. So what are you looking for precisely (a) or (b)?

Comment: I meant $f \in O(g) $ ... I am not quite 100% familiar with mathjax

Comment: And why I let it plot by WolframAlpha: According to my inequality, for $c=1$ every $x \ge 4 $ my $O(...)$ should be greater than the left side. But if you look at the graph from WolframAlpha, you see it's the case for $x$ around 40...

Comment: Are you looking for (a) or (b)? Your plot is useful only for (b), since it shows the difference, this says nothing about (a). Please make your question clear. And explain the inequality $4 \leq cx$

Comment: I have to prove or disprove (a)

Comment: I've already answered assuming the $x \to \infty$, but actually you didn't say anything about that. So, what does the $x$ approach?

Comment: The problem is that you seem not to be aware about the difference between (a) and (b). To understand an answer you need to have at least some basic knowledge of asymptotics, as I said you already in the other forums where you posted the question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I fear I have now to give it a try. The problem is that solving this requires some understanding of the meaning of the Landau symbols, but I try to make it as elementary as possible avoiding all order manipulation of the terms.
 First, it does not matter if one uses the $\ln$ or the $\log_{10}$ for asymptotic estimates here, since changing from one to the other means only multiplying by a constant, which does not change the asymptotic order.

One has:
$$ 4x\ln(x+2) = o(x^2\ln(x))$$
$$ (x+2)^2\ln(x/2)=O(x^2\ln(x))$$
This can be shown using the rule of l'Hospital.

So the first term of the lhs is negligible compared with the rhs and the second term is of the same order. Therefore:
$$4x\ln(x+2)+(x+2)^2\ln(x/2)=O(x^2\ln(x)) $$

Answer (score 0):

In order to prove the asymptotic relationship $f \in O(g)$ you have to choose both constant $c$ and $x_0$, such that the inequality $f(x) \le c \cdot g(x)$ becomes true for all $x > x_0$.

In your case you can choose $c = 8$ and $x_0 = 4$. I'll leave all the rest to you. Just a hint - you can replace $x + 2$ by $2 \cdot x$ in this case (for simplicity, because $x + 2 \le 2 \cdot x$) and do all such minor simplifications to reduce your $f(x)$ to a most simple form.

(By the way, it's a usual practice to use $n$ in such expressions)

Comment: But if I replace $x+2$ by $2x$, I replace it with something bigger, thus the inequality could become not correct anymore?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You replace parts of your expression by bigger and bigger pieces, so you'll have a chain of $\le$ inequalities - but still in the end you'll be able to choose a constant $c$ on the right side and make the final inequality true.

Comment: @Christian - this expression simplification I was talking about is a regular thing you need to employ to find functions asymptotic behavior. For example, two functions $x$ and $x + 2$ have the same order of growth, so you can just drop the constant $2$. However, if you want to use the $O$ definition, then you need inequalities, so in this case you just replace $x + 2$ by $2 \cdot x$ (with corresponding condition on $x$) - because multiplication a function and a constant doesn't change the function *asymptotic* order of growth.

Comment: @HEKTO, I fear that the OP AFAIS has a very rudimentary knowledge of asymptotics, so, forgive me, I posted something very primitive which gives a clearer hint for the solution but leaving still enough for the OP to do.

Comment: @Karl - no problem... My impression was the OP was trying to use inequalities only...

Comment: @Karl - somebody is having fun downvoting you, right? And me at the same time

Comment: @HEKTO, yes this happened to me two days ago, it was reversed and now it starts again. Four downvotes about totally different old topics.

Comment: @Karl - oh, that's tragic - an SE addict, spending his/her reputation downvoting others during holidays